# Why are browsers caching requests independent from the content-type?

Tags: html, json, browser, content-type, browser-cache

I have a URL which can be served depending on the accepted content-type. When the browser loads that page with html, everything is displayed correct. On that page, more content is loaded from that same URL with application/json.
After using a link and then going back through history to the originating page, the json content is displayed.

From chromium and firefox dev utils I can see, that they are loading the page from cache instead of requesting it again.

This is all the headers I sent:

```
Content-Length:72753
Content-Type:text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

Why are browsers caching it independent from the content type and is there a way to tell them to do it?

*update*: It looks like a bug in [chromium](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=108766) which didn't get fixed.

*update*: @T.J. Crowder answer is correct. The vary header solves the problem in chromium and firefox.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're allowing caching, then the browser has no way of knowing that you *would* change the content type if they asked for the content again.

In my view, the best thing to do would be to use different URLs for the HTML vs. JSON, allowing each to be cached to whatever degree is appropriate for them.

If you really want to have them same URL for both types, in theory the [`Vary` response header](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.44) is intended for that. It's part of the caching stuff, and tells caches (browsers, proxies, etc.) what parts of a request affect the response. [This section](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec13.html#sec13.6) is also helpful. So for instance, `Vary: Accept` would say that the response will vary depending on the `Accept` request header.

But I would test, test, test before relying on that. Cache implementations in general are notoriously buggy. But I have no specific information about bugs related to the `Vary` header.

Comment: Well, I answer the request with the same content-type the requester asked for. So nothing changes between the same request.
Apart from that, wouldn't different URLs for each content-type work against REST?

Comment: The browser sends the accept header, which I can use to compute the representation.
These URLs would mix representation with resources. That's what the accept header is for, as far as I understood.

But when browsers only use the URL as you say, that would make things much more complicated.

Comment: I accept your answer, as it seems like the only way at the moment to solve this. Firefox, Chromium and Opera ignore the resulting content-type mostly.

Comment: @Gibheer: In the shower I remembered the `Vary` header, which may be helpful. I don't know that I'd rely on it, but I have no specific information saying you shouldn't. I've updated the answer with info and links.